# VS2005 C#: is there a special visual-studio way to create properties or can the the code just be typed out?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, properties, getter-setter

Using C# in VS2005, is there special way to create properties in the IDE or can you just type out the getters and setters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code editor type `prop` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this create an automatic property which only has been added in C# 3.0 / Visual Studio *2008*? So I think this won't work for the OP then :( In case it shouldn't work it is possible to define one's own custom snippets as described here: http://aspalliance.com/863

Comment: @0xA3: No, it does work for VS2005 -- it creates a property the "old-fashioned" way (with a backing field plus a getter/setter).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can type the word `prop` and then hit tab twice for a code snippet. `propg` will generate a readonly property (only a getter).

Comment: +1 for knowing that it works in VS2005, just with the old-fashioned style backing field...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after are code snippets, [have a look here](http://aspalliance.com/863) and [here](https://www.21concepts.com/Blog/EntryId/4/Better-C-Property-Code-Snippet-for-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx).

There are also snippets besides `prop` for properties that you may save you time, [see here for the list of built-in snippets](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/vs2005-code-snippets.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in code snippets - try typing `prop` then pressing `TAB` twice. This will automatically generate the code for a property with a getter a setter, and let you tab between a couple of points to declare property name and type.